# How Bluetooth device can display incoming calls from iPhone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, bluetooth, ancs

How can I handle the incoming calls and SMS from my iPhone and immediately send data to my Bluetooth device(watches)? 
I have already implement characteristic that helps displays some data on watch's display. But I don't know how to handle incoming calls and SMS. As I understand programmers use ANCS, but I don't find how it implements.

Answer (score 1):

First, your device needs to connect with your mobile.
Followed, your device discover service (UUID is 7905F431-B5CE-4E99-A40F-4B1E122D00D0), then you could use it to get your information. More information you could see [The Apple Notification Center Service](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/AppleNotificationCenterServiceSpecification/Specification/Specification.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013460-CH1-SW8).

> **Service UUID** is 7905F431-B5CE-4E99-A40F-4B1E122D00D0.
>
> **Notification Source**: UUID 9FBF120D-6301-42D9-8C58-25E699A21DBD (notifiable)
>
> **Control Point**: UUID 69D1D8F3-45E1-49A8-9821-9BBDFDAAD9D9 (writeable with response)
>
> **Data Source**: UUID 22EAC6E9-24D6-4BB5-BE44-B36ACE7C7BFB (notifiable)